# How to set a custom taxonomy archive link to be /%category%/%taxonomy%

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm developing a WordPress site for the first time in a while and I'm looking to change the archive link for a custom taxonomy to be `/%category%/%taxonomy%`.

In my use case, categories are TV series and the custom taxonomy represents seasons. So if a post has a category of 'Star Trek: The Next Generation and a custom taxonomy of 'Season 1', I would like `/tng/s1` to show all Season 1 episodes of Star Trek: The Next Generation on the `taxonomy-season.php` template. However, at the moment this URL is displaying the `category.php` template.

Can anyone help with the correct rewrite rule? Below is all I have for the custom taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy(
    'season',
    'post',
    array(
        'public'  => true,
        'labels'  => array(
            'name' => 'season',
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => '%category%',
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: is this a custom post type as well? or is it standard posts?

Comment: @Moishy standard post :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way in Wordpress to get categories by the tag. The reason being that tags are not tied to categories, they are separate. That being said, the only way to get all tags IN USE by a specific category is to cycle through every post of the category and grab the tags of each post.

I suggest making sub categories of the parent tv show.

Then in `category.php` have an `if else` statement if its a child post etc.